# Scroll spinner horizontally to view long item

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

is there a way to make my spinner to be able to scroll horizontally?
because my item is a long sentence.

Below is my spinner screenshot, as you can see, it cut the last part of the item sentence.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Did you solve this problem? If you did, please leave the answer to the question.